# How can I guarantee the order of async writes to file under Windows?

Tags: winapi, asynchronous, io

Given this pseudo code:

1. Open file for async access
2. Write `Value1` to the end-of-file position
3. Write `Value2` to the end-of-file, in the same thread as 2.

Can I be sure that `Value1` will *always* be before `Value2` and how can I avoid race conditions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I be sure that Value1 will be -allays- before Value2, and that Value2 will not overwrite Value1

No. Win32 makes no such guarantee.

The normal approach is to manage the write position yourself, by specifying the position to start writing in the `OVERLAPPED` instance's fields. Ie. you ensure it does not matter which write completes first.

See *Synchronization and File Position* in the documentation for [`WriteFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747.aspx).

Comment: Found proof: "With asynchronous I/O support, kernel-mode drivers do not necessarily process I/O requests in the same order in which they were sent to the I/O manager. The I/O manager, or a higher-level driver, can reorder I/O requests as they are received. A driver can split a large data transfer request into smaller transfer requests." msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/

Comment: Really, the question of which write comes first is irrelevant.  You have to specify the offsets to write to when you issue the requests, since there isn't an option for "write to the end of the file" and since asynchronous handles don't keep track of a current position the way synchronous handles do.